# catkin build ONLY the message target of a package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have packages as follows:

```
package_A/
|-- msg/
    |-- CustomMsg.msg
    \-- ... (other messages)
|-- include/ ... (some code)
|-- src/ ... (some Python and C++ code)

package_B/ ... (also depends on package_A/CustomMsg.msg)

my_msgs/
|-- msg/ ... (some messages; one depends on package_A/CustomMsg.msg)
\-- ... (srv and action definitions that depend on msg)

my_package_1/ ... (depends on my_msgs)

my_package_2/ ... (depends on my_msgs)
```

I'm working in Melodic and I have some bag data, pkl files, etc., but unfortunately, I need to work with that data in another distro where it's infeasible for me to setup my workspace again (`package_A` and `package_B` won't build because of various dependencies, for example). The way I see it, I have 2 options:

**Option 1**:

I only need the messages built to work with my data, but I cannot figure out a way to get catkin to only build the message targets and ignore the code that comes in `package_A`. Is there a way to do this?

CMake doesn't come naturally to me, so when trying to build `catkin build package_A_generate_messages` failed, I decided to come here for help. If there is a way to build just `CustomMsg.msg`, even better!

**Option 2**:

I know that you can work across distros if the message hashes remain unchanged. But I don't know how those hashes are generated. Is the package name taken into account? I think the answer is yes, but wanted to check what else might be. `CustomMsg.msg` actually has a pretty simple message definition, so if I redefine the message in my own (faux) package called package_A on the other machine and build, will I end up with the same hash, which will then allow me to reuse my data files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329647/catkin-build-only-the-message-target-of-a-package/) by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2019-07-30**:
I don't know if there is a way to force catkin to only generate messages, but you could comment out all the add_executable/library/dependencies and target_link_libraries in your packages CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on 2019-07-30**:
Yeah, that's essentially what I'm doing with option 2. I think it seems to be working; I'll post back here when I'm sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you ask for is impossible, as the message generation targets are only created upon a successful CMake configuration phase run.

Success of that phase depends on the `find_package(..)` and other statements in the `CMakeLists.txt` of all pkgs in a workspace to succeed. That can only happen if all dependencies are present (which would appear to be exactly your problem: "package_A and package_B won't build because of various dependencies, for example").

The targets are defined in the `Makefile` that CMake generates after all this succeeds. At that point it would be trivial to invoke only the message generation target:

```
catkin_make package_A_generate_messages
```

or:

```
catkin build --make-args package_A_generate_messages
```

I'm not aware of any option to CMake (which Catkin will invoke) to make it ignore failing commands, so editing the `CMakeLists.txt` of `package_A` and `package_B` would seem to be your only option.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on 2019-08-02**:
Got it. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Just so I have this clear, assume for instance that instead of *missing* dependencies, which is indeed my problem, the problem was that dependency APIs had changed (for instance the arguments to a function had changed; something only caught when an actual `make` command is run)---then the option of running some `cmake` command followed by a `make <package>_generate_messages` would have been doable, right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:
If CMake is happy with whatever it found for packages, and it's just compilation that would fail, then yes, I believe you should be able to run Catkin first (which is essentially CMake) and then the message generation targets should be there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to build only parts of a package such as messages. There is, however, a third option:
Create a *new* package that contains *only* the messages. This actually a very common practice and would help avoid this issue.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on 2019-07-30**:
Yes, I know. But `package_A` and `package_B` are not maintained by me and while I do have access to the code, I do not want to incur the cost of a) collecting data again or of b) refactoring all the packages that depend on `CustomMsg.msg` since in reality there are many more than 3 or 4 packages in my workspace that depend on the message. So option 3, while valid, is a no-go.